# Data management of a representative sample

Tags: categorical-data, sampling, representative

In our original database there are some variables which are quantitative, but actually they are categorical variables. Our question is, should categorization be done in the original database or directly in the representative sample, or is it the same to do both ways?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem specific to R at all, so don't mention that in the title. More crucially it is quite unclear. Do you mean that some variables have been imported in a way that surprises you? That could be specific to R, and if so arguably off-topic here. but without code or examples it is difficult to comment.

Comment: We wonder if data management (here creating categorical variables out of numeric variables, dealing with missing data etc.) should be done in the original database and then create the representative sample for further analyses, or directly do the data management part in the sample. Thanks.

Comment: I don't find that any clearer. What is a representative sample (it's very far from an agreed standard term)? Why should it make any difference? No examples here to clarify.

Comment: May be i should have thought to explain the context bit more. Here we had a database with around 60,000 observations and we had to do survival analysis. The Schoenfeld plots which we created were very unclear due to the large number of data. So we decided to create a sample, out of the initial population. After checking that the distributions of the variables were similar in both initial database and the sample, we concluded it was representative sample. Then we realized there were some variables in numeric form, but which had to be categorized.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail, but clarify by editing the question, not by adding comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to focus on the goal.

If the goal is to improve the data structure and geometry, then I would recommend doing any change on the database itself.

If the goal is mainly to prepare the data for the analysis, then this is generally package specific (e.g. R or Stata) and is best done with the package code itself.

In any case, keep track of any changes and ensure everything can be reversed.